# how to remove border-right/Left of material-ui Textfield?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

how can i remove to "border-left" of the first textfield and 'border-right' of the last textfield

```
        <ButtonGroup variant="outlined" aria-label="outlined button group">
          <TextField label="text" color="secondary" focused />
          <TextField label="text" color="secondary" focused />
          <TextField label="text" color="secondary" focused />
        </ButtonGroup>
```

Comment: I believe you can edit your css file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [InputProps](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/) to apply class to TextField.

```
<ButtonGroup variant="outlined" aria-label="outlined button group">
    <TextField
      label="text"
      color="secondary"
      focused
      InputProps={{
        classes: {
          notchedOutline: "left"
        }
      }}
    />
    <TextField label="text" color="secondary" focused />
    <TextField
      label="text"
      color="secondary"
      focused
      InputProps={{
        classes: {
          notchedOutline: "right"
        }
      }}
    />
  </ButtonGroup>
```

Create CSS file and then import in your component.

CSS:

```
.left {
   border-left: none !important;
}

.right {
   border-right: none !important;
}
```